# Take User Input Value and Redirect

Tags: php, javascript

Basically, I have a search box. Once clicked, the value within the search box would be sanitize and then redirects as a Get Var rather than a Post.

I have one method of taking the User's Input value and redirecting to what they want to search (But it turns into a Post Method).

I want to achieve the following:

1. User Input Value: "I am Searching"
2. User/Web Client (Javascript) takes User Input Value, sanitize it for URL, and redirects.
3. User is taken to: example.com/search/i-am-searching

Rather than:

1. User Input Value: "I am Searching"
2. Server Side takes Post Value of "I am Searching" then redirects.
3. User is taken to: example.com/search/i-am-searching

Comment: What's this URL sanitizing and redirecting good for? Why not search exactly for what the user has entered? You gain nothing from making up a URL that represents only 90% of what the user has entered. *P.S.: The problem of transmitting a form via GET is already solved and does not require JavaScript, BTW.*

Comment: It sanitizing for the Address Bar so if the user inputted "#search" into the search... they would not see example.com/search/# but example.com/search/%23search I probably had mistaken for sanitizing with encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good idea could be to check how to use window.location Object.
You can check this tutorial:
[How to get url parts in javascript](http://www.suite101.com/content/how-to-get-url-parts-in-javascript-a48335)
and you can learn:

- How to obtaing the URL from the **window.location object**
- How to change the current location using **window.location.href** and **window.location.reload**
- How to split and rebuild URLs using an array and string splitting functions

In addition, you can check **document.URL** and **document.referrer**

Answer (score 1):

With:

> var value = document.getElementById('**id_of_field**').value;
>   you get the value of the field and with
>
> window.location =
>   "http://example.com/search/" + value;

Comment: Even if it did work. What would the a alternate solution if javascript was disabled?